# No minor grid lines on the x-axis only

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to product a plot in which the y-axis has both major and minor gridlines, while the x-axis has only major gridlines.

It's straightforward enough to disable minor grid lines on *both* axes, like so:

```
axes.grid(False, which='minor')
```

But I can't find a way of applying this to only one axis. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
axes.yaxis.grid(True, which='minor')
```

Similarly

```
axes.xaxis.grid(False, which='minor')
```